# Query on proof of uniqueness of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I refer to this proof: [Uniqueness of tensor product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794448/uniqueness-of-tensor-product)

In it, there is a step where $g'=(j\circ j')\circ g'$ implies that $j\circ j'=Id_{T'}$.

I am a bit confused by that step. How can we conclude that $j\circ j'$ must be the identity on $T'$?

Sure, the identity satisfies $g'=(j\circ j')\circ g'$, but does it necessarily have to be the identity?

Especially since $g': M\times N\to T'$ may not be surjective, so any element in $T'$ may not be of the form $g'(c)$ for some $c\in M\times N$.

I may be missing something obvious here.

Thanks for any enlightment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in a comment on the question that you linked to, the definition of tensor product in the question is incomplete; the factorization $h$ should be required to be unique. That correction solves the problem that you pointed out here. Both the identity and $j\circ j'$ give factorizations of $g'$ through $g'$, so they must be equal.  (Without the correction of the definition, the tensor product would not in general be unique.)